# Creating arrays in java and initialising in constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I need to create an array of objects (Cars) and then initialise the array to be of a required size (10) within a constructor. So far I have this:

```
public class Queue {

    private Car [] car;

    public Queue (Car [] car) {
        Car [] car = new Car[10];
    }   
}
```

Which when I compile says it cannot find the Car symbol. I'm presuming the problem is with the creation of the array as I don't seem to have created the Car properly. Any help would be appreciated <3

Comment: Have you defined car class??

Comment: where is the class `Car` defined ?

Comment: You're declaring a `car` variable three times: once as a field, once as a parameter to the constructor, and once as a local variable in the constructor.  None of them are actually used.

Answer (score 2):

This is the proper way to create it.

```
public class Queue {
    private Car [] car;
    public Queue () {
       car = new Car [10];
    }   
}
```

Provided that you have defined the car class.

Comment: OP also wants to initialize the array.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Car Class and put it in classpath and it will work smoothly .

EDIT[2nd time]: editing my code as per commments below. This shld work

```
public class Queue {

    private Car [] mycar;

    public Queue (Car [] car) {
        mycar = car;
    }   
}
```

EDIT:

```
class Car {

}
```

Comment: Well, except for the fact that the OP's code is wrong and doesn't compile even with the `Car` class defined.

Comment: I have not downvoted, but have you read my comment?  Your (well, the OP's) constructor for `Queue` is completely broken.

Comment: @Lokesh `car` variable in the constructor is redefined that's an error.

Comment: @Lokesh still wrong the local variable has shadowed the instance variable. You should use this operator.